# How to add an extra argument to 'will-download' event name/channel, in order to identify what triggered it

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I am trying to create a custom tracker for downloads in an electron app. The functionality I desire is to allow there to be a tracker which is created and maintained near the position where download link is clicked. In order to do this, I want to be able to pass the reference to the item which triggered this download.

```html
mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
        item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
            if (state === 'interrupted') {
                console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed');
            } else if (state === 'progressing') {
                if(item.isPaused()) {
                    console.log('Download is paused');
                } else {
                    console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}`);
                }
            }
        })

        item.once('done', (event, state) => {
            if(state === 'completed') {
                console.log('Download successful');
            } else {
                console.log(`Download Failed: ${state}`);
            }
        })
    });
```

How do I make this happen? It seems that 'will-download' triggers whenever a GET request to a file is made. How do I add arguments to this just before it is clicked? Is this information somehow retrievable from event/webContents?

Sorry if this is obvious, I am a complete noob at web-app development.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over the site containing the download link?

Comment: Yeah. I do have control over the site containing the link, but not the target of the link.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time, I found a better way to accomplish what I was trying to do, using  [electron-download-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-download-manager). I used a seperate ipc event on click, which passed the required arguments, and used electron-download-manager on main to use these arguments to create a 'monitor' channel for the specific download.

Hope this helps someone. Still curious to know whether it is possible to somehow 'overload' the will-download event with extra arguments though.

Answer (score 0):

At the momement I don't know a way to override electrons internal events, but if you have access to all download links, then you can attach a '#' with a custom value to you'r links. This way you can make them uniq and reidentify a link. The pound is a good way, in my point of view, because it has only a special meaning on client and not on server site. I would suggest the following:

```
<a href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip#test" data-progress="#progress-zipfile" download>download</a> <span id="progress-zipfile">0</span>
```

Then you can send an event from the Main-Process back to the Renderer-Process like this (example in coffee script):

```
win.webContents.session.on 'will-download', (event, item, webContents) ->
  [url, hash, rest...] = item.getURL().split /#/
  file = {url: url, id: hash}

  webContents.send 'download-started', { file: file, totalBytes: item.getTotalBytes() }

  item.setSavePath('/tmp/download.zip')


  item.on 'updated', (event, state) ->
    webContents.send 'download-updated', {
                                                 file: file,
                                                 receivedBytes:  item.getReceivedBytes(),
                                                 totalBytes: item.getTotalBytes(),
                                                 state: state
                                          }
    if (state == 'interrupted')
      console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed')
    else if (state == 'progressing')
      if (item.isPaused())
        console.log('Download is paused')
      else
        console.log("Received bytes: #{item.getReceivedBytes()}")




  item.once 'done', (event, state)  ->
    if (state == 'completed')
      console.log('Download successfully')
    else
      console.log("Download failed: #{state}")

    webContents.send 'download-completed', { file: file, receivedBytes:  item.getReceivedBytes(), state: state }
```

Within your Renderer-Process you can act on the events like this:

```
  <script>
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

    const updateProgress = function(url, percent){
      let progress =  0;
      let anchor =  document.querySelector('a[href="' + url + '"]');
      let idProgressBar = anchor.dataset.progress;

      let progressSpan = document.querySelector(idProgressBar);

      progressSpan.textContent=percent.toString() + " %";
    };

    ipcRenderer.on('download-updated', (event, arg) => {
      let file = arg.file;

      if (arg.totalBytes && arg.totalBytes > 0){
        progress = Math.round(arg.receivedBytes * 100.0 / arg.totalBytes);
      } else {
        progress = 0;
      }

      updateProgress(file.url + '#'+ file.id, progress);
    });

    ipcRenderer.on('download-completed', (event, arg) => {
      let file = arg.file;
      let progress = 100;

       if (arg.state !== 'completed'){
         progress = arg.state;
       }

      updateProgress(file.url + '#'+ file.id, progress);
    });
```